# Can I get the T-SQL query generated from a LinqDataSource?

Tags: sql, linq, .net-3.5, linqdatasource

I´m using the LinqDataSource to populate a grid. But now I need the SQL query that the LinqDataSource generates, to pass around throught methods (no, I can't modify the methods to not need a SQL query).

Is there a way to obtain the generated SQL query from a instantiated and configured LinqDataSource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps.

using the function below will return a SqlQueryText 
you can rebuild the query from that object.

- to get the sql text you can use use the .Text Property
- to get the passed
  parameters you can use the .Params property

  ```
      public static SqlQueryText GetFullQueryInfo(DataContext dataContext, IQueryable query)
      {
          DbCommand dbCommand = dataContext.GetCommand(query);

          var result = new SqlQueryText();

          result.Text = dbCommand.CommandText;
          int nParams = dbCommand.Parameters.Count;
          result.Params = new ParameterText[nParams];
          for (int j = 0; j < nParams; j++)
          {
              var param = new ParameterText();
              DbParameter pInfo = dbCommand.Parameters[j];
              param.Name = pInfo.ParameterName;
              param.SqlType = pInfo.DbType.ToString();
              object paramValue = pInfo.Value;
              if (paramValue == null)
              {
                  param.Value = null;
              }
              else
              {
                  param.Value = pInfo.Value.ToString();
              }
              result.Params[j] = param;
          }
          return result;
      }
  ```

  here is an example

  var results = db.Medias.Where(somepredicatehere);
  ClassThatHasThisMethod.GetFullQueryInfo(yourdatacontexthere, results);

EDIT:

Sorry forgot to include the SqlQueryText data structures

```
public struct SqlQueryText
{
    public ParameterText[] Params;
    public string Text;
}

public struct ParameterText
{
    public string Name;
    public string SqlType;
    public string Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run SQL Profiler while running your application and that should give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for debugging and to understand how it works.  But if you want it at run-time, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The Sql will only be generated by the Linq to Sql infrastructure at runtime.

I think there are some tools to see generated Sql in the debugger, but if you don't plan to use linq to generate your Sql dynamicaly, shouldn't you probably look for a simple Sql designer ?

I Found a Linq To Sql Debug visualizer on [Scottgu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx).

Comment: I do plan to use linq to generate my SQL dynamically. It´s just that I need the dinamically generated SQL too. And yes, the application that I´m working on is a bit... messed.